# Merge and transpose 3 arrays of data

Tags: php, arrays, csv, transpose

There are three single dimensional arrays that needs to be saved in csv

```
$arr1=array(1,2,3);
$arr2=array('a','b','c');
$arr3=array('x','y','z');
```

I need to save the above arrays in the csv like the following example-

```
1,a,x
2,b,y
3,c,z
```

I have tried the following code but its not saving in that format

```
$handle = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
$data=array($arr1,$arr2,$arr3);
foreach ($data as $line) {
    fputcsv($handle, $line);
}
fclose($handle);
```

Output

```
1,2,3
a,b,c
x,y,z
```

Comment: What exactly are you getting instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transpose the data before writing to the CSV

```
$data = array($arr1,$arr2,$arr3);
$transposedData = call_user_func_array(
    'array_map',
    array_merge(
        array(NULL),
        $data
    )
);

$handle = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($transposedData  as $line) {
    fputcsv($handle, $line);
}
fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
    fputcsv($handle, array($value, $arr2[$key], $arr3[$key]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   $arr1=array(1,2,3);
   $arr2=array('a','b','c');
   $arr3=array('x','y','z');

   $output = '';

   $data=array($arr1,$arr2,$arr3);
   $size=count($data[0]);
   //all arrays must have the same size! and $data must contain at least one item

   for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
      foreach ($data as $arr) {
         $output .= $arr[$i] . ';';
      }
      $output .= "\n";
   }

   file_put_contents($output);
?>
```

Expected output:

```
    1;a;x;
    2;b;y;
    3;c;z;
```

Comment: You need to strip the trailing delimiter from each row before adding the \n. CSV rows are terminated by a newline, not a delimiter+newline.

Answer (score 0):

try like below:-

```
$arr1=array(1,2,3);
$arr2=array('a','b','c');
$arr3=array('x','y','z');
$handle = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
for($i=0; $i<count($arr1); $i++) {
  $data=array($arr1[$i],$arr2[$i],$arr3[$i]);
  fputcsv($handle, $data);
}
fclose($handle);
```

output

```
1   a   x
2   b   y
3   c   z
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,Just take the transpose of the array before **fputcsv**

```
  <?php
 $arr1=array(1,2,3);
 $arr2=array('a','b','c');
 $arr3=array('x','y','z');
 $data=array($arr1,$arr2,$arr3);
 $rows = count($data);
 $cols = count($data[0]);
 $ridx = 0;
 $cidx = 0;

 $out = array();

 foreach($data as $rowidx => $row){
 foreach($row as $colidx => $val){
    $out[$ridx][$cidx] = $val;
    $ridx++;
    if($ridx >= $rows){
        $cidx++;
        $ridx = 0;
    }
}
}


$handle = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

 foreach ($out as $line) {
   fputcsv($handle, $line);
}
fclose($handle);
 ?>
```

**Output**

```
 1,a,x
 2,b,y
 3,c,z
```